# How to create multiple instances of JS Class/Object?

Tags: javascript

I would like to create multiple instances for apple in below code. how to achieve it. I don't want to change my object defining style.

```
var apple = {
    type: "macintosh",
    color: "red",
    getInfo: function () {
        return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
    }
}
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You will need to clone your object, in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this

```
function giveMeApple() {
    var apple = {
    type: "macintosh",
    color: "red",
    getInfo: function () {
        return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
      }
    }

    return apple;
}

var apple1 = giveMeApple();
var apple2 = giveMeApple();

// Do something with apples
```

Comment: How to execute giveMeApple(); from variable? For ex    var cloneGenerator = giveMeApple(); apple1 =  cloneGenerator; apple2 =  cloneGenerator;

Comment: @vrs As I mentioned above in my code, you need to call giveMeApply method multiple times to create new objects. So giveMeApply is not a clone generator but it instead returns an apple object.

Comment: yeah that one worked. But I need some thing like cloneGenerator variable or factory, which i am going to expose to other js libaries.

Comment: You need to understand assigning a variable to another variables multiple times won't create new objects for you. In any case, you need to call atleast one method. You can write cloneGenerator class and define a method getApple in that class and pass the object of cloneGenerator to other libraries.

Comment: `var cloneGenerator = giveMeApple; var newApple = cloneGenerator();` or look at my answer for another way to 'clone'.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a constructor function for creating instances:

```
function apple(type, color){
    this.type = type;
    this.color = color;
}

apple.prototype.getInfo = function(){
    return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
};

var apple1 = new apple('mac', 'red');
apple1.getInfo();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6S5b5/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

> The Object.create() method creates a new object with the specified
>   prototype object and properties.

```
var apple = {
    type: "macintosh",
    color: "red",
    getInfo: function () {
        return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
    }
}

var otherApple = Object.create(apple);
```

If you need to support < IE 9, the above link contains a polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Apple = function () {

            var AppleType = null;
            var AppleColor = null;
            var self = this;

            var OutPutAppleInfo = function () {
                var String = 'My Apple is ' + AppleType + ' And It Is ' + AppleColor + ' In Color.';
                console.log(String);
            }

            return {

                SetAppleColor: function (obj) {
                    AppleColor = obj;
                },
                SetAppleType: function (obj) {
                    AppleType = obj;
                },
                PrintAppleInfo: function () {
                    OutPutAppleInfo();
                }
            };
        }


        function Init()
        {
            var Apple1 = new Apple();
            var Apple2 = new Apple();
            var Apple3 = new Apple();

            Apple1.SetAppleColor('Yellow');
            Apple2.SetAppleColor('Green');
            Apple3.SetAppleColor('Red');

            Apple1.SetAppleType('macintosh');
            Apple2.SetAppleType('Food');
            Apple3.SetAppleType('Model');

            console.log('Apple1');
            Apple1.PrintAppleInfo();
            console.log('Apple2');
            Apple2.PrintAppleInfo();
            console.log('Apple3');
            Apple3.PrintAppleInfo();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this would be a case where constructor functions come in handy. [Johan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22245549/2119245) contains those. But since you don't want to change your object: Here you have another answer.

In addition to the [answer of blunderboy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22245461/2119245) you can also clone the object. There is no native function to do so, but it is easy to write one yourself.

```
function cloneObject(obj) {
    var obj2 = {},
        i;

    // Take every property of obj
    for (i in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {

            // And give obj2 the same property with the same value
            obj2[i] = obj[i];
        }
    }
}

apple2 = cloneObject(apple);
```

Comment: Or `var apple2 = $.extend({}, apple);` if he's using jQuery ;)